# Complete UI before continue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-transitions

I have a problem when on `Fragment` transitions.

I want set `ActionBar` title to `"Loading"` before switching fragment, code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Loading");
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
```

Title is setted only after the transition, that's the problem.

**Update 1:**
The problem is update the actionbar before UI thread start fragment transition (heavy task).

*PS. Sample problem if I want make two fast transitions (like, make a transition to a "loading fragment" then to the main fragment).*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
You can use a progress dialog. During the loading of progress dialog set fragment's title to whatever you want.

Comment: Dialog appear after the transition.